# Facebook Graph API for iOS search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to search places from the GraphAPI using following code without luck. Can anybody please enlight my path ?

If I try to post link/message/photo it works as expected but when trying to get location it always fails and gives me `**The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)**`

```
//Following statement is using permissions
NSArray * permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins", @"publish_checkins", nil];

[facebook authorize:FB_APP_ID permissions:permissions delegate:_delegate];  
NSString *centerString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", 37.76,-122.427];


        NSString *graphPath = @"search";
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"coffee",@"q",
                                       @"place",@"type",
                                       centerString,@"center",
                                       @"1000",@"distance", // In Meters (1000m = 0.62mi)
                                       nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:_path andParams:_params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:_delegate];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. Downloaded latest sample [HackBook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) from facebook for graph api from github and it includes sample code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

For "search" you should use "GET" instead of "POST".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

With Facebook iOS SDK, you can use FBRequestConnection after login.

```
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
                                  NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

                              } else {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                              }
                          }];
```

Answer (score 0):

With Last SDK

```
NSMutableDictionary *params2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3L];

    [params2 setObject:@"37.416382,-122.152659" forKey:@"center"];
    [params2 setObject:@"place" forKey:@"type"];
    [params2 setObject:@"1000" forKey:@"distance"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/search" parameters:params2 HTTPMethod:@"GET"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE!!! /search");
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }];
```