# How to use FB Graph search API in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am new to facebook graph api. I want to search people from facebook and show that users facebook basic information in application.How can i search people using fb graph search api. Can anyone just tell me the tutorial or any useful links for this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded latest sample [Facebook Graph API for iOS search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030266/facebook-graph-api-for-ios-search?rq=1) from facebook for graph api from github and it includes sample code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

// Calling facebook graph API

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];



SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:nil];
request.account = self.facebookAccount;

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError    *error) 
{

if(!error)
{

NSDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

//Basic profile of the user will save in list variable

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary contains: %@", list );

fbID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

//Fetching facebook ID

```
gender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list objectForKey:@"gender"]];
```

//Fetching gender
    playerGender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gender];
    NSLog(@"Gender : %@", playerGender);

Also import Social Account and security framework